# Different error codes for TCP connection refused in Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

From MSDN:

> ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
> 1225 (0x4C9)
> The remote computer refused the network connection.

> WSAECONNREFUSED
> 10061
> Connection refused.
> No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running.

What are the differences between these 2 error codes?

In which situations do we get the former, and in which situations do we get the latter?

Comment: From MSDN where? The context should provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

WSA* codes are returned by [Winsock library functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) and ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is a [general system error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-) which could be returned by any API function. In general they mean the same thing.